# For is only getting odd numbers

Tags: javascript

So I have this code that deletes options from a select (0-23) but it's only deleting 0 and odd numbers. The options that remain are 2, 6 , 10, 14, 18, 22.
The goal is to delete all options in the for
Code:

```
var x = 0; 
var select = document.getElementById("hour");
var length = select.options.length;
for (x = 0; x < length; x++) {
    select.options[x] = null;
};
```

Comment: show your select and option html part , so that it will be more easy to answer

Comment: `document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = '';`

Comment: select.options is a live list, so when you null an option, it disappears from the list, so the list becomes one shorter. So x+1 now refers to two elements from the one you just deleted, since deleting it gave the next element the index of the current element. The result is that you always skip one option. Just remove the entire innerHTML of the select. Or use something like while lastchild, remove lastchild.

Comment: Add a working code for this , so it would help us finding he mistake.

Comment: Use `x--` like  `select.options[x--] = null;`.

Answer (score 6):

Try looping reversed

```
var select = document.getElementById("hour");
var length = select.options.length;
for (var x = length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
    select.options[x] = null;
};
```

Also you may use `remove` method instead setting it to null value

```
select.remove(x);
```

**Issue with your code is, when you remove 0th index option then first one comes at 0th index resulting next iteration to delete 1st index instead current first.**

Comment: Could you add an explanation why looping reversed should solve the issue?

Comment: @3limin4t0r did that.

Comment: Why not just decrements the value of `x` like `select.options[x--] = null;` ?

Comment: There are several approaches to acheive a result. BUT pointing out what's wrong with his approach is necessary. We can clear options in one shot using `innerHtml` or using while loop or removing child etc ..but what if he need to remove option based on some condition in future ?

Answer (score 3):

Another technique for emptying an array or similar structure is to repeatedly delete the first element until there is no first element:

```
while (select.options[0]) select.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer either:

```
var select = document.getElementById("hour");
select.innerHTML = '';
```

Or

```
var select = document.getElementById("hour");
while ( select.lastChild ) {
  select.removeChild( select.lastChild );
}
```

If you mess with live node lists in a basic for-loop, the index calculations become irritating since you change the length of the options inside the loop. Hence looping backwards works as well, since the index stays the same for the previous element.